# How to change title language Wordpress Soledad

Tags: wordpress

I can't change language in the single post. I changed language in control panel, but this one element is still in english. Need help[image]

Answer (score 0):

For string translation you have two option.

1. If your site is not a multi-language site then you need to change the text directly where it.
2. if you site is multi-language then you can use the [Loco](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) translate plugin.

Note: there is also other ways are available but above are very easy